# ogr2ogr PostGIS to GeoJSON using batch file

Tags: postgis, geojson, ogr2ogr, batch, command-line

I am trying to export a PostGIS table to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr.

The following works perfectly when I launch it in Windows command :

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" F:\output.json PG:"host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" --optfile F:\query.sql`
```

However, when I save this command as a .bat file and then try to launch it in Windows command, I receive an error :

```
FAILURE: Unable to open datasource `PG:host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****' with the following drivers.
```

Is there any way I can make this command work as a .bat file?

Comment: first thing to test is using ogrinfo to check if you can connect to the database

Comment: I tested the connection using ogrinfo and there is no problem. It's only when I launch this command as a .bat file that the problem occurs.

Comment: Works for me also from a batch file. Add `ogrinfo PG:"host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" --debug on` as the first line into your batch file. Perhaps it prints some useful info for you. Do you have any odd characters that may have a special meaning for the batch file in your connection parameters?

Comment: @Ian, @user30184, I added `ogrinfo PG:"host=**** port=**** dbname=**** user=**** password=****" --debug on` to the batch file and I got the `FAILURE: Unable to open datasource` message. However, I also wrote this same command directly in  Windows command and it correctly listed all tables in my database. I have not changed the connection parameters, but I am using a French computer (could language parameters possibly change how ogr2ogr deals with a batch command rather than a direct command?)

Comment: most likely problem is that there is a "special" character in your password or user name that windows doesn't like.

Comment: @Ian,@user30184, Yes - there is an exclamation mark in my password. Is there any way to tell Windows to ignore this in the batch file or do I have to change my password?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with connection to oracle. This solve my problem (path to drivers):

```
SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=c:\OSGeo4W\apps\gdal\lib\gdalplugins
```

You should add it in your .bat file. Path depends how you installed GDAL/OGR, in my case it is OSGEO4W installation.